# Networkx: how to change a color and size of same edges?

Tags: python, networkx

I generated a graph using `networkx`

```
import networkx as nx
G = nx.grid_graph(dim=[5,5])
nx.draw(G);
```

[image]

Then I compute the minimal path between two nodes using the `astar` algorithm

```
def dist(a, b):
    (x1, y1) = a
    (x2, y2) = b
    return ((x1 - x2) ** 2 + (y1 - y2) ** 2) ** 0.5
nodes = list(G.nodes)
tmp = nx.astar_path(G,nodes[3],nodes[14],dist)
```

Now I would like to to modify the color and the size of the edges of the path between the nodes, where the nodes are defined by `tmp`

```
tmp
[(0, 3), (1, 3), (2, 3), (2, 4)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to plot each of the network's components with its own commands. Here is a working code that demonstrates how to achieve such a plot.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx

# only relevant part is treated here
G = nx.grid_graph(dim=[5,5])

node_list = [(0, 3), (1, 3), (2, 3), (2, 4)]
edge_list = [[(0, 3), (1, 3)], [(1, 3), (2, 3)], [(2, 3), (2, 4)]]

pos = nx.spring_layout(G)
nx.draw(G, pos=pos, with_labels=True)
# draw selected nodes in green with triangle shape
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos=pos, nodelist=node_list, node_size=300, node_color='g', node_shape='^')
# draw selected edges in blue with solid line
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos=pos, edgelist=edge_list, width=3.0, edge_color='blue', style='solid')
```

The output plot:

[image]

Comment: You can redo this without the circles appearing for the nodes that later get triangles if you use `nx.draw_networkx_nodes` to draw the other nodes (rather than using `nx.draw` after defining `pos`).

Comment: @Joel; Thanks. But that is not my intention.